# What is the interface between React Native and Custom Java Classes?

Tags: android, react-native

In my app I have a number of classes that perform API calls and other work. These are the models and controllers of my app. I would like to surface these to React Native so I can invoke these same methods with Javascript calls.  Most of the tutorials I have read on this are about surfacing Android API's or Components.  I am interested in surfacing my own apps API's and components.  Some of these components - perhaps most of them have asynchronous callbacks. (Separate question but also wondering if it makes sense to use fragments with React Native or not?)

Answer (score 0):

Do these custom java classes not rely on native Android functionality? If they don't it'd probably be best to convert your code to Javascript. The whole point of exposing Java/Android code via React Native bridge is to access native functionality.